# Using regex to filter pandas dataframe columns with an exception

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subset (retrieve a set of rows) a python pandas data frame by using pd.filter with a regex string to identify the columns of interest before performing a subset based on the values in those columns.

For example, this is my mock data frame:

```
id status status_drug_use drugA drugA_use    drugB  drugB_use
0  1      analgesic       0     None         1      hypertensive
1  0      analgesic       1     analgesic    1      hypertensive
2  0      analgesic       1     hypertensive 0      None
3  1      analgesic       0     None         1      analgesic
```

I would like all rows that contain the values in columns `drugA_use` or `drugB_use` which match the value in `status_drug_use`. As per the example, this would return the two rows:

```
id status status_drug_use drugA drugA_use    drugB  drugB_use
1  0      analgesic       1     analgesic    1      hypertensive
3  1      analgesic       0     None         1      analgesic
```

There are a few column name conventions to stick with:

1. `status_drug_use` is always there.
2. The matching columns (`drugA_use` and `drugB_use`) always follow the template `<ANYTHING>_use`.

**Alteration**
There is a second scenario, one in which I would like to perform a comparison between a user defined string eg `analgesic` and the two columns `drugA_use` and `drugB_use`. This is different from using the content of `status_drug_use`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what you've asked:

```py
df2 = df.assign(all_use=df.apply(
    lambda x: list(x[[col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('_use') and col != 'status_drug_use']]), 
    axis=1)).explode(
    'all_use').query('status_drug_use == all_use').drop_duplicates().drop(columns='all_use')
```

Input:

```
  id status status_drug_use drugA     drugA_use drugB     drugB_use
0  0      1       analgesic     0          None     1  hypertensive
1  1      0       analgesic     1     analgesic     1  hypertensive
2  2      0       analgesic     1  hypertensive     0          None
3  3      1       analgesic     0          None     1     analgesic
```

Output:

```
  id status status_drug_use drugA  drugA_use drugB     drugB_use
1  1      0       analgesic     1  analgesic     1  hypertensive
3  3      1       analgesic     0       None     1     analgesic
```

Explanation:

- find the subset of all columns ending in `_use` (excluding `status_drug_use`)
- add a column named `all_use` whose value for a given row is a list of the values in the columns ending in `_use`
- use `explode()` to add rows such that for each original row, there are now multiple rows, one for each of the values in `all_use` for the original row
- use `query()` to select only rows where `status_drug_use` matches the value in `all_use`
- use `drop_duplicates` to eliminate rows in case there were multiple matches for any rows in the original dataframe (for example, if both `drugA_use` and `drugB_use` contained "analgesic" and so did `status_drug_use`)
- drop the column `all_use` as we no longer need it.

**UPDATE**: Addressing OP's question in a comment: 'Rather than using the values in column status_drug_use, how do I achieve the same output but by using a single user defined string e.g., "analgesic"?'

You can do this by having the user defined query string (call it `user_defined_str`) as a variable and changing the contents of `query()` by replacing the column name `status_drug_use` with the variable name with `@` prepended: `@user_defined_str` (see the `query()` docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for more detail).

```py
user_defined_str = 'analgesic'
df3 = df.assign(all_use=df.apply(
    lambda x: list(x[[col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('_use') and col != 'status_drug_use']]), 
    axis=1)).explode(
    'all_use').query('@user_defined_str == all_use').drop_duplicates().drop(columns='all_use')
```

Comment: Thanks. Certainly does what I want. 
I've updated the original question as I have a closely related question. Rather than using the values in column status_drug_use, how do I achieve the same output but by using a single user defined string e.g., "analgesic"? The result should be the same, it only differs when None entries make there way in the status_drug_use column.

Comment: See my updated answer to address this. For additional follow-up queries, please ask a new question as that's the usual protocol (feel free to link it in the comments here if you'd like to make sure I see it).